# Read binary data from multiple files into an archive file and then extract them

Tags: python, decode, encode, archive

I want to merge multiple files to one archive. and I used python 2.7 to do this. Here is my code:

the code to read binary data from every file(some is txt with utf8 and some is png or jpeg):

```
       for we in self.entries:
        with open(we['fullname'], 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
            if not data:
                print("mpq flush error. the file no data or error:"+we['fullname'])
                break

            self.file.write(data)
```

this is ok, and all the binary data is archived into one file. and now I want to extract the archive, I do this like :

```
   def read_file(self, filename):

    if self._writable():
        print("curr mode is write, cannot read")
        return None

    entry = self._get_entry(filename)

    if not entry:
        print("the file is not in curr archive:"+filename)
        return None

    self.file.seek(entry.file_offset)
    data = self.file.read(entry.file_size)

    if not data:
        print("file read error:"+filename)
        return None

    return data


def extract_file(self, filename):

    print("extract_file:"+filename)

    data = self.read_file(filename)
    if not data:
        return

    targetFile = self._fullname(filename)

    self._makepath(targetFile)

    with open(targetFile, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data or b'')


def extract_all(self):

    for entry in self.entries:
        self.extract_file(entry.file_name)
```

every file extract success, but all data in every file extract is binary data,  I want them to be what they are before.

I tried encode and decode, but not help~

anyone can help me ? thanks very much!!!

Comment: Do you have a valid reason for not making a tar.gz file with your data? It turns it into a lossless binary blob of data and pythons tar library is pretty nice.

Comment: *"but all data in every file extract is binary data, I want them to be what they are before."* Your files were technically made up of bytes before you compressed them and they still are after extraction. It's merely a question of how you want your bytes to be represented/interpreted. Did the contents of your files change or are they simply missing their original filenames/extensions?

Comment: @pyInTheSky I want to make a mpq archive for my game. I have many resource files and I don't want to decompress them when game run because of the speed. so I want to achive all files into one and I can read them in memory.

Comment: @jDo yes I know this.  I mean  some files are txt with content like "the file is readable" but when I extract it , it'content is "0011 ddcc dddd 99de ..."，I want it to be "the file is readable"

Comment: @chenjie19891104 I think you might lack the understanding of how compression works. It's not some magic, to make your file readable again you'll have to decompress, there's no way around that. Basically you're asking "how do I remove olives from the jar without opening or breaking the jar?", see the problem there? Either leave them decompressed and make your game heavier, or leave them compressed an do decompression when you first load the game (I.e loading screen)

Comment: @chenjie19891104 you can just tar - which does not compress - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127169/does-tar-actually-compress-files-or-just-group-them-together -- and still gives you a nice archive ... the gz or bz2, etc, is the compression portion

Comment: As a nitpick, this isn't even a compression, just a concatenation. Maybe a good approach would be to have an `extract_file` function which returns a file object, and takes `offset`, `length` and `filetype` as arguments. Then you pass the file object to whatever handler is appropriate for `filetype`. For example, if the `filetype` is `txt`, you pass it to a function which converts the file contents to characters, etc.